# Add whitespace before adding XML attribute in C#

Tags: c#, xml, attributes, whitespace

I am creating XML in C#. However, I encountered difficulty for adding whitespace before the attribute value.

```
            XmlWriterSettings SettingWritterXML = new XmlWriterSettings();
            SettingWritterXML.Indent = true;
            SettingWritterXML.ConformanceLevel = ConformanceLevel.Document;
            SettingWritterXML.NewLineOnAttributes = false;

            XmlWriter objXmlWriter = XmlWriter.Create(@output_file_path + path + ".xml", SettingWritterXML);
            objXmlWriter.WriteStartDocument();

            objXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Bin");
            objXmlWriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine);
            objXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Bin");
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinCode", "001");
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinCount", tot_pass.ToString());
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinQuality", "Pass");
            objXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            objXmlWriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine);
            objXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Bin");
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinCode", "040");
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinCount", tot_fail.ToString());
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinQuality", "Fail");
            objXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            objXmlWriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine);
            objXmlWriter.WriteStartElement("Bin");
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinCode", "099");
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinCount", tot_skip.ToString());
            objXmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("BinQuality", "Null");
            objXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            objXmlWriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine);
            objXmlWriter.WriteEndElement();
            objXmlWriter.WriteString(Environment.NewLine);
```

Actual result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bin>
<Bin BinCode="001" BinCount="1465" BinQuality="Pass" />
<Bin BinCode="040" BinCount="1231" BinQuality="Fail" />
<Bin BinCode="099" BinCount="113" BinQuality="Null" />
</Bin>
```

Expected result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Bin>
<Bin BinCode= "001" BinCount= "1465" BinQuality= "Pass" />
<Bin BinCode= "040" BinCount= "1231" BinQuality= "Fail" />
<Bin BinCode= "099" BinCount= "113" BinQuality= "Null" />
</Bin>
```

*Where there is a whitespace after "=" sign in the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You're worrying about a difference that makes no difference:

- XML parsers won't care whether there's a space between the `=` and
  the attribute value.
- XML serializers do not generally expose that level of control.
- Conventionally, nobody adds whitespace there anyway.